# scale, rotate and crop images

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, image-manipulation

I want to have in my GUI capability for scale, rotate and crop images permanently (saving into the file the changes). WPF is natively capable of it? If it isn't, is there any component that can work more integrated with WPF?

I also need to adjust image brightness and contrast, remove borders, for JPEG and TIFF formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This[article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ImageCropper.aspx) posted on CodeProject explains a demo program that might be usefull for your needs.
Chek out also this [blog](http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2008/05/brightness-and-contrast-manipulation-in.html) with an article speaking about brightness levels and contrast.